# Remover item em visão específica no magento

Tags: php, css, magento, phtml

Possuo uma loja em 3 idiomas com a exibição de parcelas, sendo PT EN e ES, mas quero deixar a exibição de parcelas somente para PT.

como posso comentar essas parcelas para EN e ES? é possível?

o código da parcela é:

```
<?php
$vezes = $_product->getData('parcelas');
echo '<p><small><b>Parcele em até '.$vezes.'x sem juros</b></small><br />';

for ( $i=1; $i <= $vezes; $i++ ) {
 echo '<small>'.$i.'x de '.$_coreHelper->currency($_product->getFinalPrice()/$i, true, false).'</small><br />';
}
echo '</p>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O certo seria colocar um if no começo assim:

```
<?php
if(Mage::app()->getStore()->getName() == 'PT'){
$vezes = $_product->getData('parcelas');
echo '<p><small><b>Parcele em até '.$vezes.'x sem juros</b></small><br />';

for ( $i=1; $i <= $vezes; $i++ ) {
 echo '<small>'.$i.'x de '.$_coreHelper->currency($_product->getFinalPrice()/$i, true, false).'</small><br />';
}
echo '</p>';
}
?>
```